# Is it possible to emulate a second finger for the Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, multi-touch

It's a bit annoying having to deploy to a device everytime to test multitouch functionality so I was just wondering if it's possible to fake the second finger. Obviously plugging in two mouse's doesn't help...

Comment: I actually prefer to debug on the device. Responds faster for me than the emulator but that's probably just my lame PC.

Comment: A stupid thing is the emulator don't even support touch screens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no out of the box support for this at the moment, but there are some options you can look into for this.

[Jonas Follesø's World of Software - Simulating multitouch on the Windows Phone 7 Emulator](http://jonas.follesoe.no/SimulatingMultitouchOnTheWindowsPhone7Emulator.aspx)

[Windows MultiPoint Mouse Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/default.aspx)

[Multi-Touch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the links from Mick N, you may also want to have a look at the [MultiTouch Behavior for Windows Phone 7](http://www.galasoft.ch/touch/). As this includes support for simulating multiple touches with the emulator and a single mouse while testing.